# Play .pls file with XAML media element Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I need some help trying to make a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

i'm trying to play a shoutcast stream using a XAML media element. i've got it working in a Windows 8 Store application with the following code:

`<MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="http://37.187.79.56:3078/listen.pls;"  Width="300" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" CurrentStateChanged="MusicPlayer_CurrentStateChanged" />`

but for Windows phone it isn't working. atleast in my emulator but i have no physical device to test but the emulator plays Cortana sounds so it should play this.

Can someone help me get a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't play .pls files in WP8, just these media codecs listed in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_VideoSupport).
To stream a shoutcast radio, you will need to use [Shoutcast MediaStreamSource](https://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/). You can check a sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

.pls playlist is not supported in windows media element we have to parse the content and get the stream urls, here i pass a pls url to function and get all stream urls as list we can point media element source to any url and will play the radio

```
  public static async Task<List<string>> GetStreamsFromPLSUrl(string url)
    {



        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = false, AllowAutoRedirect = true };

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();



        try
        {


            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
            List<string> Streamurls = new List<string>();

            string line;
            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Substring(0, 4).Equals("File"))
                    Streamurls.Add(line.Substring(6));
            }

            return (Streamurls);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + "/n" + ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us how to set the source to MediaElement? thanks!